# \C-o firing twice in Emacs 26.3

Tags: key-bindings

I usually add a keybinding C-o to call other-window (in addition to default C-x o), by adding

```
(global-unset-key "\C-o")
(global-set-key "\C-o" 'other-window)
```

in my `.emacs`. However, on one machine (Emacs 26.3, MS Windows 10) this event fires twice for every key press. I can see that it actually fires twice by doing `(view-lossage)`.

This also happens if I bypass loading `.emacs` entirely and execute the `global-set-key` manually. If I manually re-bind `C-o` to any other event, for example `M-: (global-set-key "\C-o" 'next-line) RET`, that event fires twice. This does not happen for any other `C-` combinations that I've checked so far.

Any ideas what might be going on, and where I should look to fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe it would be relevant to mention your Emacs release and whether you're using Emacs in terminal mode.

Comment: Does this happen outside of Emacs as well?  (My guess is that Emacs isn't responsible).  E.g. run `cat -v` in a terminal outside of Emacs, and see what `C-o` does.